# Javascript - extract letters from an alphanumerical string via loop

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

Hello there StackOverflow people,

What I expected:
Removing the numbers of the string `"23Ka5X"`. The loop counts the length and the if statement extracts the letters into an array `letterMemory`. When no letters are in the string, the message '"oh no numbers!" should be the output.
What I ran into:
I have been working on this for some time now but I can't find my mistake. I don't know if I missed a simple detail or made a big mess.
My feeling and console output:

```js
var letterMemory = [];
    function orderMsg(mixedMsg) {
        for (var loopString = 0; loopString < mixedMsg.length; loopString++); {
          if (isNaN(parseInt(mixedMsg.charAt[loopString]))); {
           letterMemory.push(mixedMsg.charAt[loopString]);
           return letterMemory;  
        } if (!isNaN(parseInt(mixedMsg.charAt[loopString]))) {
           return "oh no numbers!";
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(orderMsg("23Ka5X"));
```

I feel like the issue is trying to push any letter into the array letterMemory via `letterMemory.push(mixedMsg.charAt[loopString])`
does not work how I imagine it.

I would be really grateful for your help!

*I found a simple solution via .replace() but I really want to make it work with a loop and if statements since loops combined with if statements were my latest freecodecamp lessons and I want to get better at it.*

Comment: Use the return statement outside for loop.

Comment: `.charAt` is a function so needs regular parentheses, not square brackets. Also `isNaN(parseInt(...))`, the `parseInt` isn't necessary as `'3'` for example is a number, even if it is in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed code

```
function orderMsg(mixedMsg){
    var letterMemory = []
    for (var loopString = 0; loopString < mixedMsg.length; loopString++){
        if (isNaN(mixedMsg[loopString])){
            letterMemory.push(mixedMsg[loopString])
        }
    }

    if (letterMemory.length){
        return letterMemory
    } else {
        return 'oh no numbers!'
    }
}
```

The issue was

1. The for loop was not executing since you terminated it with ; at the end.
2. charAt is a function, so you either do string.charAt(index), or you can also simply say string[index].
3. You are using the return statement within the for loop, so what will happen is even if the for loop ran (without the semi-colon at the end), it would run just once.
4. One other issue is that the variable letterMemory is declared outside the function so that means if you were to call this function twice, it would use the same letterMemory array.

*-end of answer-*

Additional read: you can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to condense the function as follows ..

```
function orderMsg(mixedMsg){
    const letterMemory = mixedMsg.split('').filter(isNaN)
    return letterMemory.length ? letterMemory : 'oh no numbers!'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use replace with regex globally, replacing all digits by an empty string:

```
string.replace(/[0-9]/g, "")
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just read your last comment, but I'll leave this answer if anyone needs this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful,

```
function orderMsg(mixedMsg) {
    for (var loopString = 0; loopString < mixedMsg.length; loopString++) {
        if (isNaN(parseInt(mixedMsg.charAt(loopString)))) {
            letterMemory.push(mixedMsg.charAt(loopString));
        }
    }
    return letterMemory;
}

var arr = orderMsg("23s5");
if (arr.length == 0) {
     console.log("oh no numbers!")
} else {
     console.log(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have terminated `for` loop in the same line with `;`.
2. `charAt()` is a method.
3. Return value after `for` loop ends.

   ```
   var letterMemory = [];
   function orderMsg(mixedMsg) {
       for (var loopString = 0; loopString < mixedMsg.length; loopString++) {
           var letter=parseInt(mixedMsg.charAt(loopString));
           if(isNaN(letter)){
               letterMemory.push(mixedMsg.charAt(loopString));
           }
       }
       if(letterMemory.length>0){
           return letterMemory;
       }
       else{
           return "Oh no numbers!";
       }
   }
   console.log(orderMsg("23Ka5X"));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `.test` to match the letters.

```
function orderMsg(str){
  var result = [];
  for(var letter of str){
    if(/[a-zA-Z]+/g.test(letter)){
      result.push(letter)
    }
  }
  if(result.length === 0){
    return 'Oh no numbers'
  }
  return result
}
```

For a more thorough explanation: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test